# incorrect url in Snippet editor

Tags: urls, editor

[image]I am using Wordpress version 4.9.6 with Yoast SEO premium version 7.5.3.

The trouble I am having is when I enter the Slug info in Yoast it then adds it to the URL in the Snippet editor, but it is missing the / after the domain name eg.
sitename.co.ukslug/  instead of sitename.co.uk/slug/.

in the permalink, it shows /childpage/slug but I have been told it should show the whole URL.
I have deactivated all but DLynx Framework plugin as it said do not deactivate to see if they are conflicting but made no difference.

as I am new to WordPress any other ideas on where to look would be helpful

Thankyou

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your problem?

Comment: The snippet editor is a Yoast feature. If it's not working properly you should contact Yoast support.

Comment: They looked into this for me but said it was not a problem with Yoast and possibly a plugin altering the URL which is why I disabled them to test but it made no difference.

Comment: screen shot added

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the company DesignLynx which had the plugin saying do not deactivate, they knew the issue and fixed it by removing the root relative component of framework plugin and also removed the jQuery version override.

thank you for the contributions in guiding me for the fix

gordon